# Google Charts Legend labels cut off

Tags: charts, google-visualization, google-pie-chart

The legend labels for my pie chart are being cut off when the label is too long. I have already tried to setting width to '100%' but my legend is way big to counter that. Is there a way to discretely define the pie chart size and the legend size? Could someone please share a working example of the same.

Link for JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2nzzLe18
The container div dimensions and the legend label font size are part of my requirement.

Also below is the code,

```
  google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {

    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
      ['info regarding task Work',     11],
      ['info regarding task Eat',      2],
      ['info regarding task Commute',  2],
      ['info regarding task Watch TV', 2],
      ['info regarding task Sleep',    7]
    ]);

    var options = {
      title: 'My Daily Activities',
      chartArea: {left: -100, width: '100%'},
      legend: {textStyle: {fontSize: 15}},

    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));

    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
```

Thanks,
Farhan

Answer (score 7, accepted):

it can be cumbersome to properly size a pie chart,
but it boils down to adjusting the size of the *overall* chart `div`,
and the size of the `chartArea`, where the pie is drawn (separate from the legend)

it can be tricky because it doesn't always respond how you think it should,
but I was able to get the entire legend to display

see the following working snippet,
moved the *overall* size from the `style` attribute on the `div`
to the options for the chart, then adjusted the `chartArea`

```js
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
    ['info regarding task Work',     11],
    ['info regarding task Eat',      2],
    ['info regarding task Commute',  2],
    ['info regarding task Watch TV', 2],
    ['info regarding task Sleep',    7]
  ]);

  var options = {
    backgroundColor: 'cyan',
    title: 'My Daily Activities',
    chartArea: {
      left: 0,
      height: 250,
      width: 600
    },
    height: 300,
    width: 600,
    legend: {
      maxLines: 1,
      textStyle: {
        fontSize: 15
      }
    },
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="piechart"></div>
```

Comment: thanks @WhiteHat. But i had to change to labeled legend since I am getting dynamic data with which its very difficult to assert the data i would be getting.

Comment: Pie chart with labeled legend: https://jsfiddle.net/2nzzLe18/5/. Could you please help me with changing the font styling for the % value coming in grey.

Comment: the legend labels are still coming up in 2 lines. Any chances there is an option to get it in 1 line.

Comment: there is an option for `legend.maxLines` -- but i don't think it will work unless the chart is wide enough to allow room for all the text -- changed answer above, added option for `maxLines: 1`, changed `width` & `chartArea.width` to `600` -- legend is displayed on one line...

Comment: doesn't the maxLines option work only when legend.position='top'?